# Run the SQL procedure unanswered

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I want to run a SQL procedure with DAPPER without any return on the C#.

As a command given to the SGBD that leaves worked. The C# continues regardless of the success of SQL.

It is possible?

Comment: I cannot parse this. Happy to help (I'm the primary author), but I have literally no clue what you are trying to do, or what is currently happening. Can you rephrase please? Ideally with some kind of illustrative code. Otherwise we're going to be forced to close it as unanswerable.

Comment: It sounds like they want to issue an asynchronous query, so the application continues on without waiting for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear, so I'm going to try to rephrase - if I'm close, great; if not, let me know. I think what you're asking is essentially to run a command (via a stored procedure), and have the code continue regardless of whether the command completes successfully or not. If that is the case, then simply use a `try`/`catch` region to swallow the exception. Neither dapper nor ADO.NET expose something more specific.

```
try {
    conn.Execute("MyProc",
        new { id: 42, name: "abc" }, // parameters to the proc
        commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
} catch { /* swallow it down, oh so tasty! */ }
```